# How to set multiple prices

Tags: price

Can you please tell me if it is possible in magento bookme to set more than one price? For example, on my website, I'm renting rooms,and I have different prices per months(01.-31.july 30€, 01.-30.august 50€,01.-31.september 40€). With the special price app i can't do that....Is there any method to set those prices?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Magento doesn't support that natively, but what you could do is:

1. Update your prices monthly via an import
2. Create an attribute to store the prices for the whole year (just for information purposes)